# web3js FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction contract execution from nodeJS

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, eip-1559

got a contract on ropsten network https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xa3b09a2e90ca5c97daf3846b3b9c86f1cebc9260, which is basically a copy of Hikari NFT smart contract.

I'm able to call it directly on etherscan and through https://app.mycrypto.com/send

Here's code that I'm executing (it's ropsten network so private key is included)

```
import { Chain, Hardfork } from '@ethereumjs/common'
import pkg from '@ethereumjs/tx';
const {FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction} = pkg;
import Web3 from 'web3';
import {default as common} from '@ethereumjs/common';
const Common = common.default

const ropsten = async () => {
  var provider = 'https://speedy-nodes-nyc.moralis.io/3cf9506f9d3202793daec36e/eth/ropsten';  //'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/410cef98610f45c192110f82eab4bf5e';  //'https://holy-winter-pine.quiknode.pro/0386536cf8969997c68bd3b6d2a4dd74c289635f/';
  var web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider);
  var web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);

  const hikariAbiR = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalCallerNotOwnerNorApproved","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApprovalToCurrentOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"ApproveToCaller","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"BalanceQueryForZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MintToZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MintZeroQuantity","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"OwnerQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferCallerNotOwnerNorApproved","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferFromIncorrectOwner","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferToNonERC721ReceiverImplementer","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"TransferToZeroAddress","type":"error"},{"inputs":[],"name":"URIQueryForNonexistentToken","type":"error"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_DECREMENT","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_DECREMENT_FREQUENCY","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_ENDING_PRICE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_FINAL_PRICE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_FINISHED","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_QUANTITY","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_STARTING_PRICE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"DA_STARTING_TIMESTAMP","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_TOKENS","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"NUMBER_RESERVED_TOKENS","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"PRESALE_LIMIT","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"PRICE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"addressMintedBalance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"addressMintedBalanceDA","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currentPrice","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_price","type":"uint256"}],"name":"finishDA","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"flipPreSaleState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"flipSaleState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"flipWhitelistingState","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"amount","type":"uint8"}],"name":"mintDutchAuction","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintReservedTokens","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint8","name":"amount","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"bytes32[]","name":"proof","type":"bytes32[]"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"isMarkOfLegends","type":"bool"}],"name":"mintToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"notRevealedUri","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"perAddressLimit","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"preSaleIsActive","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"presaleTokensSold","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"refundExtraETH","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"reservedTokensMinted","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"reveal","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"revealed","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"saleIsActive","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"baseURI","type":"string"}],"name":"setBaseURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"newDA_STARTING_TIMESTAMP","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setDA_STARTING_TIMESTAMP","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"_notRevealedURI","type":"string"}],"name":"setNotRevealedURI","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPerAddressLimit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"newLimit","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPresaleLimit","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"newPrice","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPrice","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"_root",
  "type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setRoot","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"_root","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"setRootML","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"index","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenOfOwnerByIndex","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"userToTokenBatchPriceData","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint128","name":"pricePaid","type":"uint128"},{"internalType":"uint8","name":"quantityMinted","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"whitelist","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
  
  const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(hikariAbiR, "0xA3b09A2e90cA5C97dAF3846B3B9c86F1cEBC9260")
  const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Ropsten, hardfork: Hardfork.London })

  const data = nftContract.methods.mintDutchAuction(1).encodeABI();
  console.log("data "+data);

  const txData = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(38),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1555555),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex('2000000000'), //2gwei
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex('50000000000'), //50gwei
    to: '0xA3b09A2e90cA5C97dAF3846B3B9c86F1cEBC9260',
    value: web3.utils.toHex('300000000000000000'), //0.3 eth
    chainId: web3.utils.toHex(3),
    data: data,
    type: '0x02'
  }

const tx = FeeMarketEIP1559Transaction.fromTxData(txData, { common });

var privateKey = Buffer.from('385231801a7734f643ebfbf336eaf5234a2ecce428da2f6cae419c2932258b3a', 'hex');

const signedTx =tx.sign(privateKey);
console.log("issigned " + signedTx.isSigned());
console.log(signedTx);

var serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();

await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
  .once('transactionHash', function(hash){ console.log("txHash", hash) })
  .once('receipt', function(receipt){ console.log("receipt", receipt) })
  .on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ console.log("confNumber",confNumber,"receipt",receipt) })
  .on('error', function(error){ console.log("error", error) })
  .then(function(receipt){
      console.log("trasaction mined!", receipt);
  });
}
```

I'm executing the function ropsten() and I only receive

```
txHash 0xb5d2bb1290aec11cdf196191e74bdb0bac344945a69f65e79485cd2020f882d1
```

and after a while

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined within 750 seconds, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
```

What am I doing wrong :| ?